# URL rewrite, remove sub directories from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I´ve looked through other answers already but they didn´t seem to work for me.
Hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction.

I'm using wordpress so got a dynamic URL which look something like:

```
www.exampleurl.nl/~projectname/lng/
www.exampleurl.nl/~projectname/lng/about
www.exampleurl.nl/~projectname/lng/news/news-item
www.exampleurl.nl/~projectname/lng/news/news-item?var=0
```

I want to remove this part from the URL `/~projectname/lng`, with the rest of the URL intact. So far the code I found didn't seem to do anything or create 500 errors. Hope this is enough information.

Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Is the projectname in your user directory does the directory name contain ~

Comment: Include the code you have tried. However, `~projectname` looks like [Apache's per-user web directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/public_html.html), in which case you won't be able to simply remove that part of the URL. (?)

Comment: @w3dk I think thats the case. My hoster said the URL needed to be changed via .htaccess. But I take it this is not something I can change myself?

When i visit the URL without the ~projectname dir I get this message 'Apache is functioning normally'

Comment: If it is a "per-user web directory" then it's not something that can be changed via .htaccess (but your host would/should know this). But the fact that you are accessing this via your(?) domain name (rather than the IP address) suggests that this is perhaps something else? But then again, that "Apache is functioning normally" message suggests otherwise. Is `exampleurl.nl` _your_ domain name? "dynamic URL" - I assume you mean "temporary" URL?

Comment: @w3dk For a client I'm hosting their website by one company but they registered their domain with another. The webhoster originally gave me an ip-adress with the '/~projectname' behind it to access the site until the DNS was resolved. But the ones handeling the DNS said the hosting should handle it and the hosting says I should handle it.

With dynamic I meant there is not a set amount of pages. Maybe a bit unclear, sorry. So far thanks for the response!

Comment: Yes, if they initially gave you just an IP address (on a shared server), then you would need to use a per-user web directory of the form `123.123.123.123/~projectname/path/to/file` (where `projectname` is the _account name_). However, once the domain has resolved then you simply drop the `~projectname` "directory" from the URL, eg. `example.com/path/to/file`. The `/lng` part is a different matter - that would indeed need some additional _internal rewriting_ on your part. But you would need to resolve the `/~projectname` issue first. (At least that's how it looks from here.)